# comparing each value in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How can I compare two columns in a dataframe and create a new column based on the difference of those two columns efficiently?

I have a feature in my table that has a lot of missing values and I need to backfill those information by using other tables in the database that contain that same feature. I have used `np.select` to compare the feature in my original table with the same feature in other table, but I feel like there should be an easy method.

Eg:  `pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,np.nan], 'B':[1,np.nan,30,4,np.nan]})`

I expect the new column to contain values `[1,2,"different",4,np.nan]`. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pandas.Series.combine_first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [pandas.DataFrame.combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) could be useful here. These operate like a SQL `COALESCE` and combine the two columns by choosing the first non-null value if one exists.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,np.nan], 'B':[1,np.nan,30,4,np.nan]})
C = df.A.combine_first(df.B)
```

C looks like:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    NaN
```

Then, to capture your requirement that two different non-null values should give "different" when combined, just find those indices and update the values.

```py
mask = ~df.A.isna() & ~df.B.isna() & (df.A != df.B)
C[mask] = 'different'
```

C now looks like:

```
0            1
1            2
2    different
3            4
4          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `pd.DataFrame.iterrows` with `nunique`:

```
import pandas as pd

df['C'] = [s['A'] if s.nunique()<=1 else 'different' for _, s in df.iterrows()]
```

Output:

```
     A     B          C
0  1.0   1.0          1
1  2.0   NaN          2
2  3.0  30.0  different
3  4.0   4.0          4
4  NaN   NaN        NaN
```